# When running ROS on the Linux subsystem of Windows 10, the terminal cannot communicate normally

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Process:
This is the process of installing the subsystem in Windows 10.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about

After I successfully installed ROS, I ran roscore normally.
When I created a new terminal, I ran rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node and it showed QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display Aborted (core dumped).
Therefore, I suspect that the two terminals I opened in Windows 10 are not communicating normally.
Q:
How can I make two terminals running on Windows 10 communicate normally?
Personal Note:
Now that Windows 10 has added the Linux subsystem, and Windows 10 and Linux can communicate with each other, I believe there will be great development prospects in the future.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/339577/when-running-ros-on-the-linux-subsystem-of-windows-10,-the-terminal-cannot-communicate-normally./) by [InsistXU](https://answers.ros.org/users/50175/insistxu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-12-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-12-10**:\

> QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display

This error typically means that you either don't have a running X server, or you haven't configured your X client correctly to use it.

Do you have an X server installed and running on Windows 10?

WSL does not include an X server.

**Comment by [InsistXU](https://answers.ros.org/users/50175/insistxu/) on 2019-12-10**:
Thanks,i solve my question by
run  vim ~/.bashrc
add  QT_QPA_PLATFORM='offscreen'
run  source ~/.bashrc
But I found a new problem, that is, after running rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node, no image will be displayed, only Spawning turtle [turtle1] at x = [5.544445], y = [5.544445], theta = [0.000000], of course This is not accidental, and rqt_graph is also unable to generate images. However, everything works fine in the virtual machine, and the subsystem and virtual machine use are both Ubuntu 16.04, and QT is the same version.

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2019-12-10**:
QT_QPA_PLATFORM='offscreen' turns the image off, so that is why it works but no image is displayed. @gvdhoorn is right, you need to install an X server on Windows, like XMing, Cygwin X or vcXsrv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@gvdhoorn is right, you need to install an X server on Windows, like XMing, Cygwin X or vcXsrv. [This tutorial](https://janbernloehr.de/2017/06/10/ros-windows) explains it in detail.

I'm copying the relevant part here for archival purposes:

> To run applications with graphical
> output, you need to install an X
> Server on Windows. To me, VcXsrv now
> works best.
>
> After you have installed VcXsrv, you
> also need to configure WSL to use it.
> To do so modify you .bashrc as follows
>
> ```
> echo "export DISPLAY=:0" >> ~/.bashrc
> source ~/.bashrc
> ```
>
> Finally, launch VcXsrv from the start
> menu. You can keep all default
> settings except "Native opengl" which
> needs to be **unchecked**. Otherwise
> applications such as rviz do not run
> as expected.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2019-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [InsistXU](https://answers.ros.org/users/50175/insistxu/) on 2019-12-13**:
Thanks for your help,